# Can this sequence be expressed with a closed-form formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49…

So if you don't count the first number the sequence is +2 for four times. After that it changes to +4 for four times, then +6, +8 and so on, all for four times.

Comment: Your sequence is unclear. How many times is it $+6$? How many times is it $+8$? Etc. Also $37$ followed by $49$ seems wrong as that is $+12$. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

[OEIS has a few closed-form formulas](https://oeis.org/A200975), including:
$$
a_n = \frac{2n(n + 2) + (-1)^n - 4\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) + 7}{8}
$$